# Missing Values: Why is isnull() not reporting NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Wondering if a `NULL` (I mean empty cell) is different from `NaN` or `na` in python. I'm checking on my dataset about missing values. But it seems pandas is not reporting all missing values.

```
df2.isnull().any()
id          False
trip_id     False
distance    False
duration    False
speed       False
foot        False
bike        False
car         False
bus         False
metro       False
mode         True
dtype: bool

df2.isnull().any().sum()
1
```

However, just checking on further, I noticed 2 missing values:

```
df2.head(10)
+---+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   |    id     | trip_id | distance | duration | speed | foot  | bike  |  car  |  bus  | metro | mode  |
+---+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0 | 441814000 |  441814 | 10632.93 |     2076 | 5.12  | False | False | True  | False | False | car   |
| 1 | 442313000 |  442313 | 738.02   |     2075 | 0.36  | True  | False | False | False | False | foot  |
| 2 | 442795000 |  442795 | 5759.29  |     3879 | 1.48  | True  | False | False | False | False | NaN   |
| 3 | 441817000 |  441817 | 31110.93 |     2948 | 10.55 | False | False | True  | False | False | car   |
| 4 | 442316000 |  442316 | 49636.50 |     2971 | 16.71 | False | False | True  | False | False | car   |
| 5 | 441316000 |  441316 | 9736.87  |     3185 | 3.06  | True  | False | True  | False | False | car   |
| 6 | 441818000 |  441818 | 10027.53 |     1181 | 8.49  | False | False | True  | False | False | car   |
| 7 | 442798000 |  442798 | 1862.62  |     2039 | 0.91  | True  | False | False | False | False | foot  |
| 8 | 442318000 |  442318 | 39738.04 |     4468 | 8.89  | True  | False | False | False | True  | metro |
| 9 | 441318000 |  441318 | 18472.13 |     5670 | 3.26  | True  | False | False | False | False | NaN   |
+---+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I wounder why `isnull().any.sum()` reports only one `NaN`

Comment: is `NaN` the string `'NaN'` or the null value?

Comment: Because you are using `any`. Try `df2.isnull().sum().sum()`

Comment: You are summing over  the series you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, it's because you are using `.any()` that will just return if any value is `NaN` you probably just want `isnull().sum()`

EDIT: This will give you the counts for each column, if you want a total value then you can do `isnull().sum().sum()` as ayhan mentioned

Comment: Ah, sure, that's is it.

Comment: Not sure if it's any better but since numpy's sum defaults to flattening then you could do: `df.isnull().values.sum()` instead of `df.isnull().sum().sum()`

Comment: @JonClements So your comment kind of peaked my interest, so I ran some timings to see if it was any faster (the only measure of "better" that I could think of) and turns out that df.isnull().values.sum() is substantially faster. 130 µs ± 932 ns per loop compared to 374 µs ± 6.19 µs for df.isnull().sum().sum()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my cell had a space, I fixed the problem replacing it for a NaN

```
df.replace(' ', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This in fact does not look like the same issue at all, does it?